# No tests found, exiting with code 0- NPM, YARN

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, yarnpkg

I want to run an application/script which was already developed by someone else. I had installed node js and yarn for executing it. When I execute that test I get something like below:

```
No tests found, exiting with code 0

Watch Usage
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press o to only run tests related to changed files.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

The scripts part of the package Json is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src/* --fix"
  },
```

I had managed to solve few dependencies issues that I was previously getting because of ESLint.

Comment: Please may you share the "scripts" part of the package json?

Comment: I'm adding that in the description.

Comment: What are the names of the files which contain tests?

Comment: There is one folder named e2e and inside that, a file named implement.me

Comment: I think the files must follow the naming conventions https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#filename-conventions

Comment: I changed the suffix to .js, I'm still getting the same issue.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of the file? Why wasn't it a JavaScript file to begin with?

Comment: The file actually does not have any code. I tried running the command yarn start. There I found the list of compilation errors.

Comment: The file even got opened in eclipse with the .me extension. I don't know why it wasn't a Javascript file, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The file actually does not have anything after I tried opening it in Eclipse. I executed the command yarn start. There, I found the list of compilation errors that I need to resolve.